# Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 - Apache2 without VirtualHost Configuration presents Website

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

please help me with the following problem:

I have a fresh installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.4 here and installed Apache2 from the ubuntu-repository.

For a test I disabled the 000-default.conf from the sites-enabled directory with a2dissite and removed the file 000-default.conf from the sites-available directory. "apachectl configtest" shows that the syntax is ok. "apachectl -S" shows, that there is no virtual host configuration. I have restarted the computer, but the Apache webserver still serves the standard Website. There are fresh entries in the "other_vhost_access.log". I wonder what configuration serves this website. I thought, when there is no conf-file enabled in "sites-enabled" apache doesn't serve any website?!

Where did I go wrong? Didn't find anything while searching. It's difficult to find the keywords.

Thanx for any help in advance.

Regards

Endi

Answer (score 0):

Apache is serving as per config settings in the main configuration files apache2.conf or httpd.conf

Comment: Thanx for your quick response. I already searched the apache2.conf file but I didn't find the directives that I know from the conf-files of the VirtualHosts. And they are not in any other file in the /etc/apache2-path as far as I did see. :(